# Call Enumerable Average via expression

Tags: c#, linq, expression, expression-trees

I'm trying to write dynamic code that do some aggregations Average, Sum, Max, etc.

That's the code im executing :

```
PropertyInfo sortProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty("PropertyName");

ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");


MemberExpression propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, sortProperty);
LambdaExpression orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);

var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(propertyAccess, parameter);

var call = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Average", new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<T>) , typeof(Func<T, int>) }, parameter);
```

and I always get that exception:

> No generic method 'Average' on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

Comment: Where does `T` come from? Is that a generic argument and thus a concrete type at runtime? I suspect you have to look for the untyped `Average` method (something like `typeof(IEnumerable<>), typeof(Func<, int>)`) and then call [`MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on that to create the version typed to `T`.

Comment: Also, shouldn't you be passing two arguments to `Call` when invoking a method that has two parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at this line. Here you're calling [`Call`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351107(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var call = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Average", new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<T>) , typeof(Func<T, int>) }, parameter);
```

The third parameter is *"An array of Type objects that specify the type parameters of the generic method."*. You're passing the types `IEnumerable<T>` and `Func<T, int>`, but `Average` [takes only a single type parameter (`TSource`)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#1828).

The forth parameter is *"An array of Expression objects that represent the arguments to the method."*. You're passing an expression representing a `T`, but `Average` expects an `IEnumerable<TSource>` and a `Func<TSource, decimal>` (or whatever overload you want to call, I'll just use the `decimal` one as an example).

I don't know what your final goal is using this code, but it probably should look like:

```
PropertyInfo sortProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty("Prop");
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
MemberExpression propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, sortProperty);

// parameter for the source collection
ParameterExpression source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<T>), "source");

var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, decimal>>(propertyAccess, parameter);
var call = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Average", new[] {typeof(T)}, source, exp);
```

Here's a small example using this code (you'll get the idea):

```
// assuming a class called T with a decimal property called Prop 
// because I'm a lazy and terrible person
var method = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<T>, decimal>>(call, source).Compile();
var result = method(new List<T> {new T { Prop=10}, new T { Prop=20}});
// result is now 15
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply , i still have and exception throw in the following line

`var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, double>>(propertyAccess, parameter);`

System.ArgumentException

Additional information: Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Double'

knowing that i've modified theat line to be 
`Expression.Lambda<Func<T, double>>(propertyAccess, parameter);`
instead of 
`Expression.Lambda<Func<T, decimal>>(propertyAccess, parameter);`

Comment: I think you should use `var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<Transaction, int>>(propertyAccess, parameter);`. `Average` has a lot of overloads so it's easy to mess up the types.